# C++11: Segfault with std::thread and lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, pthreads, stdthread

I've written a small application to demonstrate the issue, it is not pretty, but it does the job.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

class A {
 public:
  A() : thread_(), tasks_(), mutex_(), a_(99999) {}

  void Start() {
    thread_ = std::thread([this] () { Run(); });
  }

 private:
  using Task = std::function<void()>;

 public:
  void AddTask(const Task& task) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

    tasks_.push(task);
  }

  bool Empty() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

    const bool empty = tasks_.empty();

    return empty;
  }

  Task GetTask() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

    const auto& task = tasks_.front();

    tasks_.pop();

    return task;
  }

  int GetInt() { return a_; }

  void Join() { thread_.join(); }

 private:
  void Run() {
    while (Empty());

    (GetTask())();
  }

  std::thread thread_;
  std::queue<Task> tasks_;
  std::mutex mutex_;
  int a_;
};

template <class Base>
class B : public Base {
 public:
  using Base::Base;

  void Start() {
    Base::Start();
std::cout << "A: " << this << std::endl;
    Base::AddTask([this] () { std::cout << "T: " << this << std::endl; Do(); });
  }

  void Do() {
    std::cout << "Do: " << this << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GetInt: " << Base::GetInt() << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  B<A> app;
  app.Start();
  app.Join();
}
```

clang++ -std=c++11 -lpthread test_a.cpp

```
A: 0x7ffeb521f4e8
T: 0x21ee540
Do: 0x21ee540
GetInt: 0
```

Notice the change in 'this' and the value of 0 for 'GetInt'.

I'm really lost here... Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: I looked at this a bit ago, glad to see you noticed it's not specific to tcmalloc. When I looked, I found "the cause" of the problem. Sequence: `app.Start()`, main thread adds task, main thread reaches end of scope and beings destructing `app`. The `B` portion gets destructed, `A` blocks on the thread. Thread picks up the task and you get undefined behavior when it calls `B::Do` because the `B` portion no longer exists. However, I didn't post an answer because I'm actually baffled at why the value of `this` changes. :) I'll try to figure it out tomorrow if nobody figures it out.

Comment: (I mean, I could just conclude "it's undefined behavior, anything happens, don't do that". But I'd like to know why `this` would ever change in practical implementations. )

Comment: Thanks GManNickG. Could you please confirm that I've fixed the problem you've identified? If so, I should mention that the program output does not change.

Comment: Heh, I got so caught up on the bad destruction that I missed the obvious error. :) Posting an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reduced your reproduction to:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

struct foo {
  using Task = std::function<void()>;

  void Test() {
    std::cout << "In Test, this: " << this << std::endl;
    AddTask([this] { std::cout << "In task, this: " << this << std::endl; });
  }

  void AddTask(const Task& task) {
    tasks_.push(task);
  }

  Task GetTask() {
    const auto& task = tasks_.front();
    tasks_.pop();
    return task;
  }

  std::queue<Task> tasks_;
};

int main() {
  foo f;
  f.Test();
  auto func = f.GetTask();
  func();
}
```

Do you see the problem now? The issue lies with:

```
const auto& task = tasks_.front();
tasks_.pop();
```

Here you grab a reference to an object, then you tell the queue to go ahead and delete that object. Your reference is now dangling, and chaos ensues.

You should move it out instead:

```
Task GetTask() {
  auto task = std::move(tasks_.front());
  tasks_.pop();
  return task;
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh! Thank you very much :)